# Replace a switch by a JFrame with button

Tags: java, jframe, switch-statement, actionlistener

Here you have my switch from my Class Essaie with the Main() :

```
    switch(c)
    {
        case 0 :
                zero();
        break;
        case 1 :
                un();
        break;
        case 2 :
                deux();
        break;
        case 3 :
                trois();
        break;
        case 4 :
                quatre();
        break;
        case 5 :
                cinq();
        break;
        case 6 :
                six();
        break;
        case 7 :
                sept();
        break;
        case 8 :
                huit();
        break;
        case 9 :
                neuf();
        break;
        case 10 :
                dix();
        break;
        case 11 :
                onze();
        break;
        case 12 :
                douze();
        break;
        case 13 :
                exit = true;
        break;
        case 14 :
                quatorze(); //HELP
        default:
                System.out.println("\nEntrez un numero compris entre 1 et 13 (14 pour help)");
        break;
```

I would like to replace that with a simple frame that would call the same function using button to call them.

I've tried to create a class Windows and instantiate it in my main but i dont manage to link the action listener of the button of my Windows to the function in my class `Essaie`.

I'm sure that would be a lot easier to create the windows directly in the main and not use a class but i can't get the trick, can anyone help me overcome this, or give me a sample of code to create button with action listener that would call those function?

Comment: Post some code with what you've tried and we'll try to help you from there

Comment: The name of the language is Java, not JAVA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a button that calls zero() you can:

```
    JButton b0 = new JButton("0");
    b0.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            zero();
        }
    });
```

And you can add the button b0 to your JFrame. When the user clicks the button, the actionPerformed method is invoked and that will call your zero() method.